# Bootstrap 4 Active Tab based on link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to activate a tab when a specific link clicked.
This is the code sniopet from bootstrap.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

I tried using jquery:

```
  $(".tab-pane").removeClass("show active");
$("#" + activeTab).addClass("show active");
```

but it doesn't work at all, any help?
thanks

Comment: Show **your** code, too. This includes your HTML and the full Javascript related to this. E.g. you are using variable `activeTab` which you have not defined.

Comment: when you click link, page refreshed?

Comment: @AlivetoDie nothing happens, it just shows the defualt one